# Installing Material UI with SSR React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to import `@material/ui core` into a SSR React project. I have come across the following error.

> node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\objectWithoutProperties.js:1

I feel like I am missing a dependency but not sure which to install. 
Any suggestions on how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Could you update your question with your dependencies? And how are you trying to achieve this SSR?

Answer (score 0):

I need to update the babel packages:
Specifically https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime and 
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-helpers